Image classification metrics
I have been working on an image classification task using CNNs and getting some puzzling results.
My training, validation and test loss keep going down with epochs and are comparable. So this might suggest no overfitting.
But the training accuracy is higher than the test and validation accuracy (98% on training Vs 92% each on test and validation set).
It's a bit puzzling to me because typically I have seen degradation on both validation loss and accuracy when there is overfitting.
I have checked to ensure there's no data leakage. I have also ensured shuffling of training data (which I pass through an ImageDataGenerator).
One possibility I can think of is that the model is getting more and more confident about the right predictions thereby reducing loss, but consistently getting the remaining ones wrong.

Welcome to Cross Validated! How would you define overfitting? (“Training loss lower than test loss” would not be a typical definition.)
